# Change the word "Table" in table captions

Tags: tables, captions, languages, babel, naming

I need to have tables with their numbers, just as when I use `\caption`.

My problem is that when I use the `\caption` it shows me like this:

> Cuadro x.x: this is some table.

The word Cuadro is because I'm using a document class as spanish. I want to change that word "Cuadro". Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}` in your document?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since you are using `babel` with the `spanish` option, the default behaviour is to use "Cuadro" as `\tablename` (following a recommendation from the RAE); however, it is also usual, and many people prefer this regardless of what the RAE says) to use "Tabla" instead. You can use the `es-tabla` option for `babel` to change the name to "Tabla":

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
```

Another option to get "Tabla" is to use the `mexico` package option

```
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
```

but this option also changes the behaviour of the quotation marks and of the decimal separator (for details, `texdoc spanish` on a terminal).

If you want to change the name to some other string, you can redefine `\spanishtablename`:

```
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\renewcommand\spanishtablename{Otro nombre}
```

Comment: Better is `\renewcommand\spanishtablename{Otro nombre}` (no `\addto` trickery).

Comment: @JavierBezos ah, yes, I forgot about `\spanishtablename`; I updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: It helped me, but in my case i nedeed it for portuguese so i used \usepackage[portuguese,brazil]{babel}

Answer (score 33):

You can use the [`caption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/caption) package like in the following

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{name=New Table Name}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
test & test\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{test caption}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As you have it now, the change will only affect the single `table` environment to which it is applied; to have the effect global, one can say `\captionsetup[table]{name=Cuadro}` in the preamble. Besides, "Cuadro" is the current name and the OP wants to change it.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Edited my answer!

Comment: I would be very happy if somebody might tell me how I could get rid of the 1 in New Table Name 1 as I do not understand where this default option comes from. Thank you!

Comment: You can also use this package to change the name of a single table by including `\captionsetup{name=New Table Name}` after `\begin{table}` (inside the table environment)

Answer (score 4):

### With KOMA-Script

If you use package `babel` together with KOMA-Script (to be correct, package `scrbase`, which is called in the KOMA-Script classes `scrartcl`, `scrreprt`, `scrbook` and `scrlttr2` and in the KOMA-Script package `scrextend`) it is better to use the mechanism of KOMA-Script instead of `babel`s because KOMA-Script has a better verification.

KOMA-Script defines two macros for *naming* or *renaming* LaTeX names:

```
\newcaptionname{language}{LaTeX name}{new content}   % new name
\renewcaptionname{language}{LaTeX name}{new content} % renew existing name
```

For your case it is enough to add:

```
\renewcaptionname{spanish}{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}
\renewcaptionname{spanish}{\tablename}{Tabla}
```

Please note that with loading the package `scrextend` (see chapter 16, file `scrguien.pdf`, `texdoc scrguien`) you can use some KOMA-Script features with non KOMA-Script classes. For example `scrextend` loads `scrbase`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a simple solution:

```
\usepackage[tablename=Cuadro]{caption}
```

Works with and without `babel`. Use `figurename` for figures.

Answer (score 2):

## With Polyglossia

According to the Polyglossia package [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/polyglossia/polyglossia.pdf) (see *Modifying or extending captions and date formats*),

> To redefine internal macros, you can use the command \gappto from the
>   package etoolbox. For compatibility with babel the command \addto is
>   also available with the same effect. For instance, to change the
>   \chaptername for language lingua, you can do this:
>
> \gappto\captionslingua{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Caput}}

So for the tables in Spanish you would need

```
\gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
\gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}
```

Bad part is that you need to include the `etoolbox` package in your preamble. So you would use

```
\usepackage[]{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
\gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Índice de tablas}}

%...
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep the same format with caps for instance add:

```
\textsc{}
```

Such that:

```
\captionsetup[table]{name=\textsc{New Table Name}}
```