# How to locally change the "Table" caption prefix in table environment

Tags: tables, captions

In my `memoir` document, I have several tables looking something like:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{This is a caption.}
\label{tab:some_table}
\begin{tabular}{l p{10cm}}
\toprule
some text & some more text \\
\midrule
some text & even more text, it's crazy! \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

This results in the caption: "Table 3.1: This is a caption."

I would like this caption to be: "Use case 1: This is a caption."

That is, I would like to choose the prefix myself (not necessarily "Use case 1") but only locally, since my document includes other tables which should use the "standard" caption. And I want to be able to reference the tables/use cases using `cleveref` (or just `\ref` if that makes the reference "Use case 1").

Comment: You can define as many new float types as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily define new float types.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\newfloat{usecase}{luc}{Use case}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{A caption}
A table here
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{usecase}[htp]
\centering
\caption{This is a caption.}
\label{tab:some_table}

Whatever should appear here to describe the use case
\end{usecase}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the use cases to be numbered, like tables, within chapters, change into

```
\newfloat[chapter]{usecase}{luc}{Use case}
```

Adding support for `cleveref` is as easy as adding a `\crefname` instruction.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newfloat{usecase}{luc}{Use case}
\crefname{usecase}{use case}{use cases}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\caption{A caption}
A table here
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{usecase}[htp]
\centering
\caption{This is a caption.}
\label{uc:some_use_case}

Whatever should appear here to describe the use case
\end{usecase}

See \cref{uc:some_use_case}.
\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

I'll show only the relevant extract from the image:

[image]

Comment: This work perfectly, but not when I want to refer the new float using cleveref (`\cref{}`). Is it possible to use this command?

Comment: @Thomas Added; it was just to lines more.

Comment: Beautiful. `cleveref` works now too. Thanks.

Comment: can anybody explain the syntax of `\newfloat`? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: @RobertP. Section 10.1 in the manual of `memoir`.

Comment: Thanks - so `\newfloat{name_of_float}{extension_of_caption}{caption_name}`. Right?

Comment: @RobertP. Yes, and there's also an optional first argument for specifying the counter for the new float to be subordinate to. For other classes, you can consider the `newfloat` package.

Comment: @egreg: actually, I am using the command above in a `article` class, and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

As found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/80443/change-the-word-table-in-table-captions): You can use the `caption` package.

To blatantly rip off @azetina,

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
{
\captionsetup[table]{name=New Table Name}
\begin{table}\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
test & test\\
\end{tabular}
\caption{test caption}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

In order to do this for all tables, move the `\captionsetup` command into the preamble.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  For this to work the `\captionsetup` should be outside the table in an enclosing group.  Also note the poster asks about the `memoir` class.  In any case the link to answer works and we should perhaps close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: The other question seems to be global (although similar). Also the `\cref{}` doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to fix this?

Comment: @Thomas, Yes, it was global in the final edit, but at first (before edits) it proposed this method which was local...